# List<Char> typed constexpr string in C++

Tags: c++, constexpr

I am trying to emulate `cons-cell`like list structures from functional programming languages, in C++ using `constexpr`. I have a `pair` type, to begin with. This is a holder of two different things but supports nested pairs as well. Here is the code.

```
template <typename E1, typename E2>
struct pair {

    constexpr pair() 
    :_car{E1{}}, _cdr{E2{}}
    {}

    constexpr pair(const E1 &car, const E2 &cdr)
    :_car{car}, _cdr{cdr}
    {}

    constexpr auto car() const{
        return _car;
    }

    constexpr auto cdr() const{
        return _cdr;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                                    pair<E1, E2> p){
        if(p == pair{})
            return str;
        str << p.car() << " " << p.cdr();
        return str;
    }

    template <typename Functor>
    friend constexpr auto fmap(Functor f,
                               const pair<E1, E2> p){
        if constexpr (std::is_fundamental<E1>::value &&
                      std::is_fundamental<E2>::value)
            return pair{f(p.car()), f(p.cdr())};
        else if(std::is_fundamental<E1>::value &&
                !std::is_fundamental<E2>::value)
        return pair{f(p.car()), fmap(f, p.cdr())};
    }

    const E1 _car;
    const E2 _cdr;
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
constexpr bool operator==(const pair<E1, E2>& p1, const pair<E1, E2>& p2)
{
    return (p1.car() == p2.car()) && (p1.cdr() == p2.cdr());
}
```

As a wrapper around this type I have a `nested_pair` type. This makes it easier for me to work with `nested_pair`s .aka lists. The actual list is just a typedef around this wrapper. Here is the code.

```
template <typename Head, typename Tail>
class nested_pair{
    public:

    constexpr nested_pair():p{}
    {}

    constexpr nested_pair(Head h, Tail t)
    :p{h, t}
    {}

    constexpr auto prepend(Head h) const{ 
        return nested_pair<Head, decltype(p)>{h, p};
    }

    constexpr auto head() const {
        return p.car();
    }

    constexpr auto tail() const {
        return nested_pair<decltype(p.cdr().car()),
                    decltype(p.cdr().cdr())>
                    {p.cdr().car(),
                     p.cdr().cdr()
                    };
    }

    constexpr bool is_empty() const {
        return p == pair<decltype(p.car()),
                         decltype(p.cdr())>
                         {};
    }

    template <typename Functor>
    friend constexpr auto fmap(Functor f, const nested_pair l) {
        const auto res = fmap(f, l.p);
        return nested_pair{res.car(), res.cdr()};
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                                    nested_pair<Head, Tail> l){
        str << l.p;
        str << "\n";
        return str;
    }

    private:
    const pair<Head, Tail> p;
};
```

My `nested_pair` only allows prepend because append requires O(n) recursive calls if you store your list as a pair of head and tail. Here, I delegate a lot of work to the `pair` and `nested_pair` constructor that packs a `pair`. These works fine I believe. I use following variable template to define lists as nested pairs.

```
template <typename T>
using list = nested_pair<T, T>;
```

Now, to the meat of the question, I want to use this `list` to make a `string` type, as in `list<char>`. This should again be all constexpr, as much as we can make it. I have an other version taking `const char []` to build constexpr strings but now I want to use structural recursion. Here is my failed attempt.

```
class lstring{
    public:

    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr lstring(const char(&cont)[N]) :size{N} {
        size_t ind = N - 1;
        while(ind >= 0){
            content = content.prepend(cont[ind]);
            ind--;
        }
    }

    private:
    const size_t size;
    const list<char> content;
};
```

Of course this does not work. constexpr constructor goes through a while loop and violates the rules of constexpr, I believe we can't loop in a constexpr function. This also, do not take advantage of recursive structure of lists as well. How can  I construct a string this way? Should I use a variadic template that takes a `char... args`? How can I unpack this structurally? I want to be able to initialize this from a string literal like `list<char> s{"hello world"}`.

Comment: C++14 constexpr functions can have loops.

Comment: Ok, that I suspected but that still would not help me to take advantage of recursive structure.

Comment: @meguli • `constexpr` is for compile-time evaluation.  Are you trying to do "emulate cons-cell-like list structures from functional programming languages" during compile-time?  q.v. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: @Eljay Yes, that's what I am trying to do and I think my `list` implementation is working to some extent, should be enough to build a `list<char>` specialization.

Comment: I see some problems in you code but the bigger is that `prepend()` return a different type. I mean... you place a `nested_pair<char, char>` in `lstring`; but the first call to `prepend()` return (if I understand correctly) a `nested_pair<char, nested_pair<char, char>>`, then a `nested_pair<char, nested_pair<char, nested_pair<char, char>>>` and so on. So the final type depend from `N`.

Comment: @max66 I am well aware of that and tried hard to overcome it but don't know a way around. I am not using any pointers and C++ needs to know the size of the type. Thus, structure needs to be part of the type.

Comment: @meguli - I see... Not clear what do you exactly want... I have an half idea but I have to develop it... But do you want a solution based on your `pair` or do you interested also in a `constexpr` head/tail solution based on completely different set of classes?

Comment: @max66 You can see my last question for the approach I chose.

Comment: @meguli - interesting... but (if I understand correctly) you have different types for string of different lengths... well, I'll try to develop my idea and, if works, I'll propose it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conceptual issue:

Your `lstring` contains a `list<char>` which actually is a `nested_pair<char, char>` which in turn contains a `pair<char, char>`. **Your strings contain always two `char`s.**

Both the string class as well as the list class need to encode their length as part of their type. I.e. you need a `list<char, 5>` for a list of 5 `char` (thus containing a `pair<char, pair<char, pair<char, pair<char, char>>>>`). Otherwise you'd need dynamic memory -- which is a clear *no* for compile time constant code.

---

Now, on for a demonstration. I hope it'll give you some ideas on how certain things can be implemented. Also it was fun for me ;) Contrary to your design choice I go with a special sentinel value - `nil` - to mark the end of a list. All of the following code is in a `namespace list`:

```
 struct nil {
  template<typename U>
  constexpr auto prepend(U && u) const;
 };
```

`nil` (the empty list) has a member function template to add something to the front. It's only declared - not defined - here to break a cyclic dependency.

*Note: Whether to even use member functions or free functions here is a matter of personal taste/style. Normally I'd go with free functions (`prepend(mylist, element)`) but I wanted to mirror your intended usage (`mylist.prepend(element)`).*

Next comes the most important structure - the "pair" - on which lists are built. Named after Lisp's cons cells:

```
 namespace implementation {
  template<typename T>
  using no_ref_cv = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
 }

 template<typename Car, typename Cdr>
 struct cons {
  Car car;
  Cdr cdr;

  template<typename U>
  constexpr auto prepend(U && u) const {
   using implementation::no_ref_cv;
   return cons<no_ref_cv<U>, cons<Car, Cdr>>{std::forward<U>(u), *this};
  }
 };
```

It's just a simple pair. `prepend` creates a new cons with the new element as its first element and (a copy of) the current cons as it's second. I remove `const` and `volatile` because it's otherwise a bit of a headache (try figuring out why `cons<char, cons<char, cons<const char, cons<char, nil>>>>` won't convert to `cons<char, cons<const char, cons<char, cons<char, nil>>>>`)

That said, the implementation of `nil::prepend` is basically the same:

```
 template<typename U>
  constexpr auto nil::prepend(U && u) const {
   using implementation::no_ref_cv;
   return cons<no_ref_cv<U>, nil>{std::forward<U>(u), *this};
  }
```

Also I like free functions to "make" things, so:

```
 template<typename Car, typename Cdr>
 constexpr auto make_cons(Car && car, Cdr && cdr) {
  using implementation::no_ref_cv;
  return cons<no_ref_cv<Car>, no_ref_cv<Cdr>>{
    std::forward<Car>(car), std::forward<Cdr>(cdr)};
 }
```

Now, on to your questions:

> How can I unpack this structurally? I want to be able to initialize this from a string literal like `list<char> s{"hello world"}`.

`list<char>` won't be possible (remember -- you need the length there, too!). But `auto s = list::make_list("hello world")`.

You already have code to get the length of the string literal (parameter type `CharT (&array)[N]`) and with that `N` you can build a type with enough nested `cons` to hold your list:

```
 namespace implementation {
  template<typename T, std::size_t N>
  struct build_homo_cons_chain {
   using type = cons<T, typename build_homo_cons_chain<T, N - 1u>::type>;
  };

  template<typename T>
  struct build_homo_cons_chain<T, 0u> {
   using type = nil;
  };
 }
```

`N == 0` is just a `nil` (empty list), everything else is a `cons` with the element and a list of length `N - 1`. This allows you to define the correct type for your list, which you could use to default initialize an instance of it and then loop over the `car` member's to fill it. Something like this:

```
using list_t = typename implementation::build_homo_cons_chain<char, N>::type;
list_t my_new_list;
// fill my_new_list.car, my_new_list.cdr.car, ... probably with recursion
```

The issue with this approach is that you require the element type of your list to be both default constructible as well as assignable. Not an issue for `char`, but these are tough requirements, so we're better of when we copy / move construct the list's elements from the elements supplied in the array (string literal):

```
 namespace implementation {
  template<std::size_t O, std::size_t C>
  struct offset_homo_builder {
   template<typename T, std::size_t N>
   constexpr auto from( T (&array)[N]) {
    return offset_homo_builder<O - 1u, C - 1u>{}.from(array).prepend(array[N - O]);
   }
  };
  template<std::size_t O>
  struct offset_homo_builder<O, 0u> {
   template<typename T, std::size_t N>
   constexpr auto from( T (&array)[N]) {
    return nil{};
   }
  };
 }
```

`O` is an offset relative to the *end* of the array, `C` the count of cons we still need to build the list. The `from` member function template takes an array of length `N` and prepends the element from the array at `N - O` to the (shorter) list it builds recursively.

Example: `implementation::offset_homo_builder<3,2>::from("ab")`

```
offset_homo_builder<3,2>::from("ab") --> N = 3, O = 3, C = 2
: cons{'b', nil}.prepend('a') => cons{'a', cons{'b', nil}}
  ^
  |--- offset_homo_builder<2, 1>::from("ab") --> N = 3, O = 2, C = 1
       : nil.prepend('b') => cons{'b', nil}
         ^
         |--- offset_homo_builder<1, 0>::from("ab") --> N = 3, O = 1, C = 0 (!specialisation!)
              : nil
```

The `C` count is important to leave out the `'\0'` at the end of the string literal. So now you can make a list with all elements of an array:

```
 template<typename T, std::size_t N>
 constexpr auto make_homogenous(T (&array)[N]) {
  return implementation::offset_homo_builder<N, N>{}.from(array);
 }
```

Or build a string where the last element is left out:

```
 template<std::size_t N, typename CharT, typename = typename std::char_traits<CharT>::char_type>
 constexpr auto make_string(CharT (& array)[N]) {
  static_assert(N > 0, "assuming zero terminated char array!");
  return implementation::offset_homo_builder<N, N - 1>{}.from(array);
 }
```

Finally, for working with this list you don't need to look at the element's type. Just stop at `nil`:

```
 template<typename F, typename Car, typename Cdr>
 constexpr auto fmap(F functor, cons<Car,Cdr> const & cell) {
  return make_cons(functor(cell.car), fmap(functor, cell.cdr));
 }
 template<typename F>
 constexpr auto fmap(F functor, nil const &) {
  return nil{};
 }
```

`foldl`, `foldr` and friends can be implemented similarly. Your `operator<<` can the be implemented using `foldl`.

*End of the `namespace list`.*

Also, checking that we're still `constexpr`:

```
constexpr char inc(char c) {
 return c + 1;
}

static_assert(fmap(inc, list::make_string("ab").prepend('x')).car == 'y', "");
```

*Note the beauty of [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL) ... I can say `fmap` instead of `list::fmap`. Good for generic code.*

Comment: These type of simple dependent types are what I wanted to have in the beginning but I could not find a way to make the correct pair a member of the type. For example, when I have `list<char, 5>`, it needs to have a member with type `pair<char, pair<char, pair<char, pair<char, char>>>>` but what `list<char, 1>` is going to have? Each needs to have a member with different type as well. I don't know how can I achieve this.

Comment: I'll post an example for you in a few hours ;)

Comment: As I said in the main thread, you can look at my last question to see the approach I am trying right now.